# Where do you store validation logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm playing around with the [MVC.Validation Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/MvcValidatorToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=16935). The goal is to use the same validation rules in client script and in the server code.

However i keep making new [poco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) classes for everything.
I have one class from linq2entities, then I got one class that is passed from the datalayer to the business layer, then to the controller. And I have another viewmodel class just for passing data to the view.

I can't find a way to get around this last class, as I need to use different validation rules at different times.

The validation attributes are defined on the view model class. This don't see to be the best way.

Anyone have any experience at using this Toolkit?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to check out this tutorial and see if it is relevant
http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-37-cs.aspx

Main point is - you can implement IDataErrorInfo with your model class  wich mvc is aware of.